# Represent linestrings with arrow direction based on origin and destination points location

Tags: qgis, postgis, attribute-joins, direction, representation

I have two layers:

- one linestring layer with two attribute fields that identify the codes of the origin (field A) and of the destination (field B) nodes;
- one point layer with one attribute (unique value) that identify the code of the node represented by the point. This code matches with that's either in the field A or in the field B of the linestring.

How can I represent the linestring as arrows going from A to B?

Comment: What is currently in the line layer ? does the line already exist but don't connect the point ? are you trying to update their geometry ?

Comment: the ends of each line (it's a road network) are located where the related points (that represent the ends, A and B) are located. I want either to update their geometry (with some kind of join?) or create a new layer that it's not just lines, but directional lines (arrows). The trouble is that the info on which point is A (origin) and which is B (destination) for a specific line is stored as attributes in the line layer, not in the point layer which only has a field with the identifier (same code that appears in A or B in the line layer).

Comment: Is the point layer necessary? Or are there instances where the first point in the line is not point A or the last point in the line point B? Also, remember to add any info in the comments back into the question.

Comment: yes it's necessary as the information on where A and B are is in the points layer. A is always origin and B destination.

Comment: Maybe you can add a screenshot or two? From what you have explained, I could just extract A and B from the first and last points of the linestring layer. So possibly there is something I am missing.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest not to modify your actual line layer (if they are road they may be not straight line and won't be accurately represented by a direct line from A to B) but rather create a new layer. For that you may use the "Geometry by expression" tool or create a virtual layer depending on your later need. Alternatively you may add a new symbol layer to your line layer symbology using geometry generator symbol layer type.

In any case to create the geometry you could use an expression in the following form (this expression assume that the source layer is the line layer):

```
make_line(
        geometry(get_feature('POINT_LAYER_NAME', 'POINT_ATTRIBUTE_FIELD', "FIELD_A")),
        geometry(get_feature('POINT_LAYER_NAME', 'POINT_ATTRIBUTE_FIELD', "FIELD_B"))
        )
```

Note that the field name from the point layer is between single quote while the field A and B are between double quote.

Comment: I tried using the same expression both with Geometry by expression and Geometry generator in symbol layer. Both return a visually blank layer, so apparently the symbology doesn't work

Comment: There is probably a problem with the expression, try to build it incrementally starting with the 'get_feature' function to see if you get the right point